# Aggregate query results by custom field in Django ORM

Tags: sql, django, django-models

We have a simple model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    created = models.DateField()     
    title = models.CharField(max_length=210) 
    content = models.TextField()
```

Is there a way to implement the SQL query with Django ORM?

```
SELECT YEAR(created), COUNT(*)
FROM Post
GROUP BY YEAR(created)
```

I can write raw SQL, but I want to avoid it...

Answer (score 0):

Django provide it's own query set for making queries you can do like

```
   Post.objects.values('created').annotate(dcount=Count('created'))
```

don't forget to import

```
from django.db.models import Count
```

anyway you can also check your query like

```
>>> queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
>>> print queryset.query
SELECT "myapp_mymodel"."id", ... FROM "myapp_mymodel"
```

Comment: Can i aggregate by YEAR(created)?

Comment: of course you can go through link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset   and makr as correct if you satisfied

Comment: There is no aggregation function Year. I can't use 'created__year' as an aggregation field as well...